# How to calculate mean value in R between initial timepoint and 24 hours later

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a healthcare dataset in which I have to calculate the average score of a value within the first 24 hours of an ICU admission and I am playing around with dplyr and the **filter** function and the **between** statement but I keep getting 0 observations.

For example I have this dataset with reproducible data including converting the date time to POSIXct because that's what I have in my original dataset:

```
test<-structure(list(MRN=structure(c(001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 002, 002, 002), 
                   label="MRN"),
                   Encounter_ID=structure(c(001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 100, 100, 100), label="Encounter_ID"),
                   ICU_FIRST=structure(c("2018-01-03 19:37:00", "2018-01-03 19:37:00", "2018-01-03 19:37:00", "2018-01-03 19:37:00", "2018-01-03 19:37:00", "2018-03-04 05:00:00", "2018-03-04 05:00:00", "2018-03-04 05:00:00"), label="ICU_FIRST"),
                   Record_Time=structure(c("2018-01-03 20:00:00", "2018-01-04 00:10:00", "2018-01-04 09:20:00", "2018-01-04 13:00:00", "2018-01-06 13:00:00", "2018-03-04 13:00:00", "2018-03-04 17:00:00", "2018-03-05 13:00:00")),
                   Value=structure(c(5, 5, 3, 9, 4, 7, 10, 20))),
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

test$ICU_FIRST<-as.POSIXlt(test[["ICU_FIRST"]],"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")
test$Record_Time<-as.POSIXlt(test[["Record_Time"]],"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")
```

^I want to calculate the mean value for each encounter ID whose **Record_Time** is >=**ICU_FIRST** and <=**ICU_FIRST**+24 hours. In such an instance, for Encounter_ID 001, I would want rows 1-4 but not row 5 counted in calculating the mean value. Likewise for Encounter ID 002, I would want rows 6 and 7 included in calculating the mean value, but not row 8.
I tried playing around with this code in dplyr:

```
df %>%
  arrange(MRN, Encounter_ID, ICU_FIRST, Record_Time)%>%
  group_by(Encounter_ID, ICU_FIRST, Record_Time)%>%
  filter(between(Record_Time, ICU_FIRST, (ICU_FIRST+86400))) %>%
  summarise(mean_value= mean(value))
```

Any suggestions for how I can troubleshoot this code would be much appreciated, thank you! I'm also open to solutions using other packages aside from dplyr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple base-r solution uses `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Value ~ Encounter_ID, 
    data = test[test$Record_Time >= test$ICU_FIRST & test$Record_Time <= (test$ICU_FIRST + 60 * 60 * 24),], 
    FUN = mean
)
```

The first argument is your formula, in the format `numeric ~ grouping`. The `data` argument is where you apply your 24h (in this case, 60s * 60m * 24h) time window filtering. `FUN` specifies that you want to apply the `mean` function to the rows that you have not filtered out.

This can be done with pipes and dplyr as well if you prefer that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here a tidyverse solution.

```r
test<-structure(list(MRN=structure(c(001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 002, 002, 002), 
                   label="MRN"),
                   Encounter_ID=structure(c(001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 100, 100, 100), label="Encounter_ID"),
                   ICU_FIRST=structure(c("2018-01-03 19:37:00", "2018-01-03 19:37:00", "2018-01-03 19:37:00", "2018-01-03 19:37:00", "2018-01-03 19:37:00", "2018-03-04 05:00:00", "2018-03-04 05:00:00", "2018-03-04 05:00:00"), label="ICU_FIRST"),
                   Record_Time=structure(c("2018-01-03 20:00:00", "2018-01-04 00:10:00", "2018-01-04 09:20:00", "2018-01-04 13:00:00", "2018-01-06 13:00:00", "2018-03-04 13:00:00", "2018-03-04 17:00:00", "2018-03-05 13:00:00")),
                   Value=structure(c(5, 5, 3, 9, 4, 7, 10, 20))),
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# test$ICU_FIRST<-as.POSIXlt(test[["ICU_FIRST"]],"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M", tz="")
# test$Record_Time<-as.POSIXlt(test[["Record_Time"]],"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")

test
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>     MRN Encounter_ID ICU_FIRST           Record_Time         Value
#>   <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>               <chr>               <dbl>
#> 1     1            1 2018-01-03 19:37:00 2018-01-03 20:00:00     5
#> 2     1            1 2018-01-03 19:37:00 2018-01-04 00:10:00     5
#> 3     1            1 2018-01-03 19:37:00 2018-01-04 09:20:00     3
#> 4     1            1 2018-01-03 19:37:00 2018-01-04 13:00:00     9
#> 5     1            1 2018-01-03 19:37:00 2018-01-06 13:00:00     4
#> 6     2          100 2018-03-04 05:00:00 2018-03-04 13:00:00     7
#> 7     2          100 2018-03-04 05:00:00 2018-03-04 17:00:00    10
#> 8     2          100 2018-03-04 05:00:00 2018-03-05 13:00:00    20


library(tidyverse)

test %>%
mutate(ICU_FIRST=lubridate::ymd_hms(ICU_FIRST)) %>%
mutate(icu_24=ICU_FIRST+lubridate::hours(24)) %>%
filter(Record_Time>=ICU_FIRST)  %>%
filter(Record_Time<=icu_24) %>%
group_by(Encounter_ID) %>%
summarise(mean_value=mean(Value))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   Encounter_ID mean_value
#>          <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1            1       5.67
#> 2          100       8.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>